# I have checkbox image in UICollectionViewCell which I want to show as selected or unselected?

Tags: ios, swift, grid, uicollectionview

I want to select all and deselect all cell of `collectionView` using select All and deselect all `UIButton`? 
Please help anyone.

```
//Delegate Method cellForItemAtIndexPath
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
UICollectionViewCell
{
    //Get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
                                                            "pickSomecell",
                  forIndexPath: indexPath) as!      pickSomeGridViewController
    //Show Images in grid view
    cell.cellImage.image = self.arrAllOriginalImages[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
     cell.toggleSelected()

     //return cell.
     return cell
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have checkbox image in UICollectionViewCell which you want to show as selected or unselected?

Comment: Yes @BhumitMehta 
But i want to select all images together.

Comment: Can you post your code in CellForItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Yes sure @BhumitMehta 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do as follow-

```
 var isSelectAll=false


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UICollectionViewCell
    {
        //Get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
            "pickSomecell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath)
        //Show Images in grid view

        if isSelectAll {

            cell.cellImage.image = selectedImage;
        }else{
            cell.cellImage.image = desselectedImage;
        }


        return cell
    }

@IBAction func selectAllcell(sender: AnyObject) {

    isSelectAll=true
    collectionView.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func deselectAllcell(sender: AnyObject) {

    isSelectAll=false
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Ok let me try .  
Thanks a lot.